# Get each selected value using chosen jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using Chosen Multiple Select 
What I want to do is that if user selects any option I want that value and then I will do some functionality depending on that value.

In chosen without multiple select i can get selected value by using foll. code

```
$(".selectId").chosen().change(function(){
     selectedValue = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

But in multiple select I get the first selected value again n again
can anybody help me by finding the current selected value in multiple select element??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [Chosen documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html) mentions parameters for getting the most recently changed variables.

> Chosen triggers the standard DOM event whenever a selection is made
>   (it also sends a   selected or deselected parameter that tells you
>   which option was changed).

So, if you just want the most recent option selected or deselected:

```
$(".selectId").chosen().change(function(e, params){
 // params.selected and params.deselected will now contain the values of the
 // or deselected elements.
});
```

Otherwise if you want the whole array to work with you can use:

```
$(".selectId").chosen().change(function(e, params){
 values = $(".selectId").chosen().val();
 //values is an array containing all the results.
});
```

Answer (score 17):

**Short answer:**

You just do this: `var myValues = $('#my-select').chosen().val();`

**Full example:**

If you have a select-multiple like this:

```
<select id="my-select" class="chzn-select" multiple data-placeholder="Choose one or more values...">
  <option value="value1">option1</option>
  <option value="value2">option2</option>
  <option value="value3">option3</option>
</select>
```

You can get the selected values in an array to doing the following:

```
// first initialize the Chosen select
$('#my-select').chosen();

// then, declare how you handle the change event
$('#my-select').chosen().change(function(){
    var myValues = $('#my-select').chosen().val();

    // then do stuff with the array
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is gettin the correct selected value.. but since its multiple you need to use loop..or use `map` to get the selected  value and  push it into array..

try this

```
 $(".selectId").chosen().change(function(){
    var  selectedValue = $.map( $(this).find("option:selected").val(), function(n){
              return this.value;
       });
    console.log(selectedValue );  //this will print array in console.
    alert(seletedValue.join(',')); //this will alert all values ,comma seperated
});
```

**updated**

if you are getting commaseperated values then use `split()`

```
 var values=  $(".selectId").val();
 $.each(values.split(',').function(i,v){
     alert(v); //will alert each value
     //do your stuff
 }
```

Comment: Thanx for instant help. But it throws this error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1' in 23

Comment: `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1' in 23` weird... doesnot sound the error is getting from the addedcode.. did u try comment this.. and tryin it out.. see if you get the error again..

Comment: I want to do some functionality for each selection. I can get all selected items by using $(".selectId").val(); But i want one by one value and as user selects item i want to display that current selected value in some div element on each selection

Comment: `$(".selectId").val(); ` is this giving you an array.. if yes thn you can loop through the array and use each one.. :)

Comment: No it give me comma separated values

Comment: Hey see the scenario:- I have three items: item1, item2,item3,. Now if i select item3 then i will display item3 in some div element. after that i select item 1. As i select item1 this value will append to that div. i.e. now my div has item3 and item1. I want that in the same sequence of selection.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $('.selectId:selected').each(function(i, selected) {

var value = $(selected).val();
var text = $(selected).text();

});
```

Comment: Hey thanks. But  
I want to do some functionality for each selection. I can get all selected items by using $(".selectId").val(); But i want one by one value and as user selects item i want to display that current selected value in some div element on each selection

Comment: here value means you will get one value only.did you observed it is in each loop

Comment: Hey see the scenario:- I have three items: item1, item2,item3,. Now if i select item3 then i will display item3 in some div element. after that i select item 1. As i select item1 this value will append to that div. i.e. now my div has item3 and item1. I want that in the same sequence of selection.

Answer (score 0):

The [Chosen documentation](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) mentions parameters for getting the most recently changed variables.

```js
$(".CSS Selector").chosen().change(function(e, parameters) {
  // params.selected and params.deselected will now contain the values of the
  // or deselected elements.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've got it to work. In my html, I've this

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="form-control chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="UK">UK</option>
    <option value="CHINA">CHINA</option>
</select>
```

Then javascript

```
// apply chosen-js to the DOM, and store it in a variable.
var chosen = $(".chosen-select").chosen({
   no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
}); 

// inside the change event, we get the value by calling chosen.val()
chosen.change(function() {
   console.log('selected tags are', chosen.val());
});
```