# Getting the value of specific list <li> items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-chosen

I have multiple chosen select options on my site. Chosen saves the selected values into a list

Now I need to get this selected values to save them into a database. I found a solution with `document.getElementsByTagName('li')` but this get's all my `li` items including the select options I don't need there right now. How can I specify the `li/ul` I'm looking for?

Here my current `JavaScript` status:

```js
function() {
  var elementsLI = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  var length = document.getElementsByTagName('li').length;
  for (var i = 0; i <= length; ++i) {
    alert(elementsLI[i].value);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="chosen-choices">
  <li class="search-choice"><span>Erdnuss</span></li>
  <li class="search-choice"><span>Andorra</span></li>
  <li class="search-choice"><span>Anguilla</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But what is exactly the `li` you expect?

Comment: So how are we supposed to know what is selected? Are they all selected if they are in the select?

Comment: Using the UI to get the data you need is a bad practice as this layer should be kept for presentation only.
You should model your data and make it detached from any UI implementation.
I'll make an example for you if you'll create a working snippet of your full use case

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403220/get-each-selected-value-using-chosen-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Your question is an X/Y problem

You show the rendered CHOSEN UL instead of the code with a runnable chosen select.

Here is how to get the values of a `chosen` multiple select. You use the .val() just like in an normal select

```js
$("#sel")
.chosen()
.on("change",function() {
 console.log($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css" />

<select id="sel" multiple>
  <option value="Erdnuss">Erdnuss</option>
  <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
  <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".search-choice").forEach(choice => {
  console.log(choice.firstChild.textContent)
})
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.